# Safely disable WIn10 device drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, sleep

I have a new HP Pavilion laptop with Win10.  Recently it started crashing whenever it enters sleep mode.  Only a hard shutdown will bring it back up.

I suspect the problem is a driver that was automatically installed by HP, since I am able to successfully put it to sleep when I boot in Safe Mode.

I tried using Driver Verifier, but it BSOD'd on boot every time without any indication of the faulty driver.

So I want to narrow down the faulty driver by disabling a bunch at a time and seeing if I can sleep.  But I'm worried about disabling a critical driver and preventing the system from booting.

Which drivers in Device Manager are mandatory and would prevent the system from booting if disabled?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: No.  I found the problem -- it was the RealTek Audio Driver.  I uninstalled it, let Windows re-install it, and it's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any important files, I personally would consider wiping the drive entirely and installing a fresh copy of Windows 10. It would probably be less time-consuming.

On a side note, I think that the crucial drivers depend on your hardware.

Comment: Thanks, that was my fallback plan.  But I'm afraid that the bad driver will get installed again and I'll be back where I started.

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks.